# Website Issues - cant find the solutions

Tags: html, css, optimization

First of all i dont know if its permited more than one question in one topic, however i didnt find anything talking about that.

I have been developing a website, but im a bit new to this and my site has some things that need to be worked out, i will be listing the issues bellow and hopefully someone will help me.

1- Slideshow

- How i can put the circles (bullet navigation) of the slideshow inside the slideshow ?
- Images are not fully the size as the screen, i can see the current slide and a bit of the next slide, what do i do ?

2- Last 2 pages, Mobile & Contacts

If i change

```
.mobile {
 min-width: 1100px;
}
```

to:

```
.mobile {
min-width: 1300px;
}
```

The mobile div will not make text stay on top of the image but the contacts page will not be as responsive as before, just try by yourself.

Thats it, it may simple, but i cant figure it out, i hope theres no problem with this topic, if so tell me.

See it live: http://optential.co.nf/

```css
html,
body { height: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("img/fundo1.jpg");
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 650px;
  position: relative;
}

.header .logo {
  width: 230px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 20px 8px 8px 6%;
}

.header .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px; right: 25px;
}

.header .menu a {
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 20px;
}

.header .menu a:hover,
.header .menu a.current {
  color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
}

.header .move {
  color: white;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header .move .center {
  margin: 260px auto 0;
  width: 360px;
}

.header .move h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 38px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.header .move p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.header .mail1 {
  background-image: url("img/email.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 560px; height: 560px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.header .mail1 form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 240px;
  bottom: 220px; right: 155px;
}

.header .mail1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);

}
.header .mail1 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
 }

.header .mail1 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.header .mail1 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.header .mail1 a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.header .mail1 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 {
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 15px grey;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("img/barra.png");
  background-position: 12% 0%;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: right;
}

#btn {
    width: 10em; 
  }

.mail2.fixed {
  box-shadow: 10px 6px 15px grey;
  position: fixed;
  display:block;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mail2 form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 600px;
}

.mail2 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgb(203, 41, 37);
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mail2 input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 220px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 218);
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0 6px;
}

.mail2 input:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 188);
}

.mail2 input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.mail2 a {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 4%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.mail2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.mail2 .top {
  padding: 8px 6px;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.mail2 .top:hover {
  background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
}

#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .images { 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 1s;
  left: 0;
}

#slider .images img {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.controls {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.controls div {

  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.controls .current {
  background: red;
}

.mobile {
  min-width: 1300px;
}

.mobile .bar {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F4F4F4;
  color: #595B61;
  min-width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile .bar img {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mobile .content {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 55% 50%, #F9F9F9 40%,#B6B5BD 120%);
  position: relative;
}

.mobile .content .mobimg {
  padding: 3em;
  margin-left:10%;
}

.mobile .content .mob {  
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0;
  left: 60%;
}

.mobile .content h1 {
  color: #D6D6D4;
  font-size: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mobile .content p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 410px;
  color: #929584;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 18px
}

.mobile .content .sep {
  height: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C24147;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile .content .sep img {
  padding: 0 8px;
  background: #F9F9F9;
}

.mobile .content h2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #929584;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile .content .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.mobile .content .button {
  display: block;
  background: #010101;
  color: #F8F8F8;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile .content .button:hover {
  background: #222;
}

.mobile .content .button.apple img {
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.mobile .content .button.apple span {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px; left: 42px;
}

.mobile .content .button.apple h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px; left: 42px;
  margin: 0;
}

.mobile .content .button.google img {
  margin: 18px 0 0 8px;
}

.mobile .content .button.google span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px; left: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mobile .content .button.google h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px; left: 38px;
  margin: 0;
}

.mobile .content .button.google h3 b {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Cardo', serif;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 4px
}

.contact {
  min-width: 1100px;
  background-image: url("img/fundo2es.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height:100%;
  color:white;
}

.contact .textocon {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 55px 75px 0 0;
}

.contact .textocon div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 290px
}

.contact .textocon h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.contact .textocon p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 19px;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.contact .col1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 410px;
  padding: 10px 6px 10px 60px;
}

.contact .col1 h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

.contact .col1 input {
  width: 380px;
  height: 20px;
}

.contact .col1 input,
.contact .col2 textarea {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgb(172, 161, 160);
  margin: 6px 0;
}
.contact .col1 input:focus,
.contact .col2 textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.contact .col2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 560px);
  padding: 52px 10px 10px 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.contact .col2 textarea {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 112px;
}

.contact .col2 #btn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgb(204, 66, 63);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.contact .col2 a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(224, 86, 83);
}

.contact .info {
  padding: 10px 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.contact .info h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.contact .info p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.contact .info a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.contact .info a:hover {
  color: #ddd;
}

.contact .info img {
  width: 32px;
  margin: 6px;
}
.contact .info img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fixedbar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title> Layout </title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="header" id="top">
      <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="current">Home</a>
        <a href="#tour">Product Tour</a>
        <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a href="#">Try</a>
        <a href="#vision">Vision</a>
      </div>
      <div class="move">
        <div class="center">
          <h1>Move work forward!</h1>
          <p>Optential keeps your team organized, connected, and focused on results.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mail1">
        <form action="form/form.php" method="post">
          <h1>Try Now!</h1>
          <input name="Email" class="Email" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email address ...">
          <input type="submit" value="Get started for free">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mail2">
        <form action="form/form.php" method="post">
        <h1>Try Now!</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email here...">
        <input type="submit" id ="btn" value="Get started for free">
        <a class="top" href="#top">Top</a>
      </form>
    </div>


    <div id="slider">
        <div class="images">
          <div class="controls">
          <img src="img/3.png" alt="Image-1" />
          <img src="img/2.png" alt="Image-2" />
          <img src="img/1.png" alt="Image-3" />
          <img src="img/4.png" alt="Image-4" />
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>

     <div class="mobile">
      <div class="bar">
        <img src="img/barra2.png">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img class="mobimg" src="https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/mob.png">
        <div class="mob">
          <h1>Mobile</h1>
          <p>Optential combines the best of responsive software with native IOS and Android apps to provide the best experience and optimal results!</p>
          <p>On laptops, desktops, tablets and phones, always get the best experience on the most intuitive project management set of tools in the world!</p>
          <p class="sep">
            <img src="https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/a1.png">
          </p>
          <h2>Get the app!</h2>
          <div class="buttons">
            <a class="button apple" href="">
              <img src="https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/apple.png">
              <span>Download on the</span>
              <h3>App Store</h3>
            </a>
            <a class="button google" href="">
              <img src="https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/google.png">
              <span>Get it on</span>
              <h3><b>Google</b>play</h3>
            </a>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
      <div class="textocon">
        <div>
          <h1>Optential</h1>
          <p>A new management system<br>for a new management paradigm!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form method="POST" id="contactos_form" action="form/contactengine.php" onsubmit="return submit_form(this);">
        <div class="col1">
          <h1>Contact us!</h1>
          <input type="text" name="Name" size="50" placeholder="Name"/>
          <input type="text" name="Email" size="50" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="text" name="Subject" size="50" placeholder="Subject"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
          <textarea name="Message" rows="5" cols="70" placeholder="Message..."></textarea>
          <input type="submit" id="btn"value="Send"/>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="info">
        <div>
          <h1>Mail Us !</h1>
          <p>Rua Andrade Corvo, 242</p>
          <p>sala 206</p>
          <p>4700-204 Braga</p>
          <p>Portugal</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Call Us !</h1>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>+351 987654323</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Email Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><p>code@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_hr@angel.com</p></a>
          <a href="#"><p>code_support@angel.com</p></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>Join Us! </h1>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/gplus.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/instag.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script>
function submit_form(form){
  formulario=$("#contactos_form");

   $.ajax({url: formulario.attr("action"), method:formulario.attr("method"), data:formulario.serialize(), success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }});


  return false;
}


</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The css of the slideshow is "slider" and "controls".

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer questions 1**

I will be answering the others shortly. To move the button controls first we need to give them a div, however as the controls are being dynamically generated so we have to edit the code which creates them, to do this we go into slider.js and add `class="button move"` to the

```
$('#slider .images img').each(function(i) {
  var img = $(this);
  img.css('left', i * width);
  var button = $('<div class="buttonmove">');
  controls.append(button);
  if (i == 0) {
    button.addClass('current')
  }
```

Now we have something that we can edit, the most easiest way to move them is to use `position:relative` and give them a -100 top value like so.

```
.buttonmove {
    position: relative;
    top: -250px;  
}
```

**Question 2**

Unfortantly I don't see the issue with your question as changing it 1300px works better as the layer don't overlap, please let me know in more detail;

A- the problem
B- what the result should be like

I hope this helped!

**EDIT**

Here is the jQuery function;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var sliderImgH = $(".sliderimages:first").height();
     $(".buttonmove:nth-child(1)").css("margin-top", sliderImgH-75);
});

$(window).resize(function() {
     var sliderImgH = $(".sliderimages").height();
     $(".buttonmove:nth-child(1)").css("margin-top", sliderImgH-75);
});
```

I also added this CSS;

```
.buttonmove {
    position: relative;
}
#slider {
    position: absolute;
}
```

*NOTE**

Adjust your function order so it goes or it won't work on load,

```
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
```

Then the function I just made

```
<script src="js/fixedbar.js"></script>
```

**EDIT(sorry forgot to add...)**

I forgot to tell you to to add a class called `sliderimages` to your first or all of the images in your slider.

```
<div id="slider">
        <div class="images">
          <div class="controls">
          <img class="sliderimages" src="img/3.png" alt="Image-1" />
          <img src="img/2.png" alt="Image-2" />
          <img src="img/1.png" alt="Image-3" />
          <img src="img/4.png" alt="Image-4" />
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, with stays where i want with top: -35px;but it changes postion when you resize the window browser.

Comment: @BugaDroid I see, so you want it pinned just to the bottom of the pictures?

Comment: I created that function and added that css but dont seems to work.

Comment: @BugaDroid Sorry I'm an idiot I forgot to tell you to add a class to your images, I have updated the answer. Hope it works now it is on mine